# How compare ping result with ttl

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want in ping only show result with TTL between 100-225

```
Pinging x.x.x.x with 32 bytes of da
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=124ms TTL=128
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=148ms TTL=64
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=127ms TTL=64
Reply from x.x.x.x: bytes=32 time=140ms TTL=128
```

thanks

Comment: What about `findstr`?

Comment: *"I want"* is not a question, so please be specific! Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! As a starting point, take a look at [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Test-Connection` cmdlet to do this.  For example:

```
Test-Connection <TargetServerName> | 
    Where-Object {$_.TimeToLive -ge 100 -and $_.TimeToLive -le 225} |
        Format-Table __Server, Address, TimeToLive -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with a batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('ping 10.28.2.38 ^|findstr /B /C:"Reply from"') do (
    set "ping=%%G"
    set "TTL=!ping:*TTL=!"
    SET "TTL=!TTL:~1!"
    IF !TTL! GEQ 100 IF !TTL! LEQ 225 echo %%G
)
```